# Is a twitching sensation near the elbows during push ups an indicator af bad technique?

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, exercise-technique, push-ups

When doing push ups I tend to get a twitching sensation around my elbows towards the end of my workout. For push ups I tend to do 3 sets of to failure (12-16 reps). It usually occurs during my last set and almost always in both arms at the same time. The location of the twitching is on the inside of the upper arm very close to the elbow (I'm  guessing where the triceps tendon connects to it). I started working out half a year ago and I had it since then.

The sensation is not painful or even discomfortable; It is distracting at most.  As such this question is not meant to ask for medical advice. I was just looking for the anatomical reason for why this occurs and whether or not it is a result of bad technique. I am certainly not flaring my elbows, so I am not sure what I could be doing wrong.

I also noticed it happens quicker when not properly warmed up or during colder temperatures. This observation is just anecdotal however and might be coincidence.

Answer (score -1):

A twitching sensation in joints is often caused by tight ligaments. This will happen no matter the quality of your form. Sometimes it can be improved by and be improved by warming up more but sometimes but sometimes a person just has naturally tighter ligaments in some or all joints.

Comment: [citation needed]